# Why does VC++ 2010 Express say "Evaluation"?

Tags: visual-c++, evaluation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visual Studio Express 2010 license](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624589/visual-studio-express-2010-license)

I was under the impression that the express version of Visual C++ 2010 was free for commercial use. However, when I start it up, the slash screen says that the app is for evaluation use only.

What gives?

Comment: You need to register it for that to go away. Duplicate : (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627942/is-visual-studio-2010-express-edition-free)(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627942/is-visual-studio-2010-express-edition-free), (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624589/visual-studio-express-2010-license)(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624589/visual-studio-express-2010-license)