# Visual C++ Express Edition

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-c++

I am using Visual C++ Express Edition. And I have the following queries in it..

1) Can I distribute the executable that I got from VC++ express edition for commercial purpose?
2) How to get a common executable for 32 bit and 64 bit architecture using Visual C++ express edition?

And my another doubt is..
Using "Mingw" how to generate a common executable for 32 bit and 64 bit architecture.

thanks.

Comment: Have you read the Terms of Use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624589/visual-studio-express-2010-license

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes, there are no licensing restrictions for applications built using Visual Studio Express Editions.
2. Just build a 32-bit executable. It will work properly on 64-bit Windows because it will run under the WOW64 subsystem. The same thing applies for other Windows C++ compilers, like MinGW.

   If you really want to compile a separate 64-bit application, you will need to download and install [the latest version of the Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279). it includes 64-bit tools, including a 64-bit compiler. These tools are not included with Visual C++ Express.