# Can I build a commercial Internet Explorer BHO using VISUAL C++ 2010 EXPRESS?

Tags: visual-studio, internet-explorer

I don't have any experience building software for Windows but I have experience with C++ and with software development in general.

I now need to develop a commercial Internet Explorer BHO and I wanted to do it using freeware - can I use Visual C++ 2010 Express for this or do I need the pay-for edition?

Thanks.

P.S.: I am aware it is not going to be an easy task.

Comment: If I recall correctly, building anything commercial with Express versions of Visual Studio is forbidden.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Express 2010 license](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624589/visual-studio-express-2010-license)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving licensing issues aside, there is no technical reason why you can't build a BHO using it.  Eventually you will need to buy a code signing certificate, but other than that you can do it all free.

Comment: One technical caveat is that Express doesn't include ATL which you could use to simplify COM code.

Comment: I would be careful about using ATL.  CComPtr<> is useful, but the wrappers for things like, say IConnectionPoint and such are difficult to use and debug unless you really understand the underlying technology.